# How to apply Diatomaceous Earth on my succulents?

Tags: pest-control

I am searching for a way to treat scales on my Haworthias. One product that drew my attention is diatomaceous Earth. Is this effective against scales? What is the best way to apply it? The plants are relatively small, and I think of applying it with a paintbrush. This will allow me to spread the dust into all nooks and crannies that I can see, and let some of the dust settle between the leaves as well.

Comment: I scrape off scales with a finger nail; fast, effective.

Comment: Actually new scales occupy the the place where the scraped ones once lived. They seem to multiply quite quickly.

Comment: I did not have any returns when I scrapped over 100 off a large staghorn fern.

Answer (score 1):

Diatomaceous earth is only effective against soft bodied insects that move.  Adult scales will not be affected but juveniles will.

If you can get a type of Diatomaceous earth that has permethrin in as well that will work even better as that will improve the residual activity

Another low tech solution is to put the plants outside under shade cloth and let natural predators do their thing